# FireFox - element referenced by id name in the global scope. use w3c standard.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this message for this part of my code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) { } 
}
```

I cant seem to fix it. Can anybody help or shed some light?

Comment: Do you have an element with ID `window` or `document`?

Comment: On a different subject, I strongly suggest you avoid using the unstrict equality "==" operator in javascript and switch over to the strict equality "===" operator as it is safer, (for example "5" == 5 but "5" !== 5)

Comment: Why? un-strict equality is very dangerous. I myself appreciate constructive code criticism when I show code. The == operator in javascript is a major problem and bug causer. http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from your syntax being wrong it is working for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/Qu82q/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $window=$(window);
    if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) == $(document).height()) { 

    } 
}
```